# Show Metadata in Sharepoint 2010 columns using Infopath forms

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I'm trying to show some metadata fields in Sharepoint 2010. I'm aware that you can use Infopath to create a form and select the fields you want to show, but it seems that there's an issue when trying to select fields from the extended properties, instead of the core ones. 
Can anyone explain me how to fix it?

Comment: It seems you lost a few words: "...but it seems that there's an **[...]** when trying...".

Comment: sure! sorry, i've already corrected the mistake

Comment: What "issue" exactly are you talking about? Do you get some error message? What do you see and what would you expect?

Comment: I expect to see the value of the metadata field but I see nothing. For example, I want to make visible the following fields with their values: "Subject=Eva", "Company=Hi", "Manager=Hey". But when I upload the form to Sharepoint, the fields Company and Manager appear void, but Subject doesn't.